# How to customize constraint violation messages?

Tags: postgresql

I want define my own message for each constraint. Is it possible to customize constraint violation messages in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This has been asked in Postgres Forum: [Custom Constraint Violation Errors](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-general/2011-11/msg00275.php)

and after some discussion:

> ...
>   So am I got that right, that If I want to have eg custom error messages
>   for a foreign
>   key violation, I need to replace all fkeys by trigger functions?!
>
> Michael Musenbrock

answered there:

> > The short answer is, while it is possible to custom make your
> >     own constraint triggers that emulate foreign keys, don't do it.  This
> >     would be a maintenance nightmare.
> >
> > I'd be more maintainable to catch these errors in your client
> >     application.  Here you would reword these error messages according the
> >     business rules of your client application.
> >
> > Richard Broersma Jr.

with what I think would work best:

> > > It's not hard to create:
> > >
> > > ```
> > > CONSTRAINT some_constraint_name FOREIGN KEY col REFERENCES blah(id)
> > > ```
> > >
> > > ... then in the app, match `"some_constraint_name"` and map it to a suitable error. That's what I do and it works very well for all constraint types, not just foreign key constraints.
> > >
> > > --
> > >       Craig Ringer